# ADXL345 sampling rate setting

Tags: raspbian, python-3

I want to set ADXK345 sampling rate.
I wrote the following code in python3

```
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import Adafruit_ADXL345
import threading
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import os
import sys
import shutil
import numpy as np
#import readchar
#Frequency
Fre=800


#record time
recotime=20

SAMPLE=800*20
tstr7=[None]*SAMPLE
T=timedelta(microseconds=1000000/Fre)
print(T,'microseconds')
now1 = datetime.now()
tstr1 = now1.strftime("%m%d-%H-%M-%S")
tstr = now1.strftime("%m%d-%H-%M-%S")
os.chdir("/home/pi/Desktop")
os.mkdir(tstr)
os.chdir(tstr)

SAMPLES = Fre*recotime
RESOLUTION = 3.9
accel = Adafruit_ADXL345.ADXL345(address=0x1d,busnum=1)
accel.set_data_rate(Adafruit_ADXL345.ADXL345_DATARATE_3200_HZ)
#tstr7=[]

def record1():
    memory1 = tstr1
    df = pd.DataFrame(l1)

    df.columns = ["x","y","z"]
    df *= RESOLUTION
    #df["time"]=pd.Series(scipy.array(range(SAMPLES))*execution_time1/SAMPLES)
df["now"] = pd.Series(tstr7)
#df = df[["time","now","x","y","z"]]
df = df[["now","x","y","z"]]
df.to_csv("/home/pi/Desktop/{0}/{1}.csv".format(memory1,tstr3))
print("record1succcess")



l1 = [None] * SAMPLES

timebefore=datetime.now()
while(True):



    now3 = datetime.now()
    tstr3 = now3.strftime("%m%d-%H-%M-%S")

    i=0
    c=0

    while(True):
        i=0
        starttt=datetime.now()
        while(True):
            nowtime=datetime.now()
            if(T<nowtime-timebefore):
                 #print(nowtime-timebefore)
                 timebefore=nowtime
                 l1[i] = accel.read()
                 #print('',l1[i])
                 tstr7[i] = nowtime.strftime("%m%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")[:-2]
                 i=i+1

                 if(i==SAMPLES):
                     endttt=datetime.now()
                     t1 = threading.Thread(target = record1)
                     t1.start()
                     print('',endttt-starttt)
                     break
```

Result:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo python3 gdgd.py
0:00:00.001250 microseconds
0:00:20.210241
record1succcess
0:00:20.927121
record1succcess
0:00:20.919855
record1succcess
0:00:20.801644
record1succcess
0:00:20.812261
record1succcess
0:00:20.840028
record1succcess
0:00:20.818875
record1succcess
0:00:20.834642
record1succcess
0:00:20.880220
record1succcess
0:00:20.826976
record1succcess
0:00:20.827458
record1succcess
0:00:20.854751
record1succcess
0:00:20.834181
record1succcess
0:00:20.891394
record1succcess
0:00:20.835767
record1succcess
```

I set the sampling rate to 800Hz and recordingtime to 20 seconds,
But in practice the recording time exceeded 20 seconds.
I want more accurate data. I had the Internet and looked into various things, but I couldn't solve it.

Is there a good solution?

Comment: Ah, let me see. I googled but could not find ADXK345.

Comment: And why not set ODR to much less than 800?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  I want more accurate data is a meaningless statement.  Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: The code says ADXL245 not ADXZ245. Please fix your post.

Comment: I googled and found two AdaFruit ADXL345 Libraries, one seems not for python, another is for python but DEPRECATED. Are you using any updated library? References: (1) AdaFruit Unified driver for the ADXL345 Accelerometer - Last update 4 years ago
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADXL345

(2) Adafruit Python ADXL345 - DEPRECATED LIBRARY last update 3 years ago
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_ADXL345

Comment: If you find your python library, you may try to find the relevant section to set the data rates for you situation. Some useful tips are: 
(3) Digital Accelerometer ADXL345 - Analog Devices
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf

(1) Table 7 - Data Rate consideration 
(2) Page 21  - Modes such as overrun, bypass, fifo, trigger, also to adjust data rate,
(3) BW Rate register 0x2C to set data rate and power mode,  You read the datasheet very carefully and then read the library functions to see if you can modify some code to suit your requirements.